# ReSharper doesn't seem to respect .editorconfig

Tags: c#, resharper, editorconfig

I have used ReSharper for a while and generally use the Implicit option for private modifiers in C#.  However, I'm working with someone else who prefers private modifiers to be explicit, so we agreed to do it explicitly for this solution.  The solution has an .editorconfig file that should do this, from my understanding, but it's not and I'm not sure why (I've never used .editorconfig before).

When I go into my ReSharper settings (latest ReSharper build) it shows my implicit setting but also shows that it's being overwritten by EditorConfig with a value of Explicit:

[image: Modifier Type Declaration]

However, in my warnings dialog I'm still getting a bunch of these:

[image: Private warning]

It even shows explicit on the menu:

[image: current setting]

What are we doing wrong?

Shouldn't it be skipping that warning for this solution based on EditorConfig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enabling the `ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings | Read settings from editorconfig and project settings` checkbox.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!  Out of curiosity why would that not be checked by default?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you. In case you would like to get the full explanation of why it is OFF by default, you are welcome to check out the blog post https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/07/27/performance-improvements-resharper-2018-2-eap-editorconfig-support/. Long story short: it was disabled by default from the beginning due to performance reasons. Most of them have already been fixed, however, there are still a few which we are working on.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation, that makes total sense.  This is why I love SO :).